# Removing a cardview item inside a recycler view if it is null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a recycler view in which I populate a cardview consists of an image and two text fields. It works fine. What i want to know is there some way to remove an image from cardview if it is null (and not showing the blank space for image)and just show the text fields for that specific item in recycler view.

I am parsing a JSON service containing images and text. But some of the images are missing while parsing data and I want to remove that image space while displaying data.

Below is my Cardview.xml i am using inside Recyclerview adapter.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contextClickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
        android:background="#CCC" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"

        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:background="#CCC" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brief"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contextClickable="true"
        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
        android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHighlight="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/brief"
        android:background="#CCC" />


</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The RecyclerViewAdapter class is :

```
 private LayoutInflater inflater;
 Context context;
 List<Data> dataArray;
 private int lastPosition = -1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
    //this.dataArray = dataArray;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void setDataArray(List<Data> dataArray) {
    this.dataArray = dataArray;

}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Data current = dataArray.get(position);
    holder.textView1.setText(current.heading);
    holder.textView2.setText(current.date);
    holder.textView3.setText(current.brief);

    // Using picasso to fetch image as the user scrolls down ... No need to store
    // all the images during start up.

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(current.getLImage());
        //System.out.println("URIiii issss::::"+uri);
        Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(holder.image);
        // Animation
        setAnimation(holder.relativeLayout, position);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataArray.size();
}


public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView image;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        textView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        textView3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brief);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
    // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated

    if (position > lastPosition || position < lastPosition) {

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }

}
}
```

What i really want is to remove the imageview item inside carview if it is null. I am relatively new to android, so any guideline would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you upload your adapter source?

Comment: set the visibility of imageview to GONE if url is null

Comment: can you please post any url for which image is getting null ? @Umair

Comment: i have added answer.. let me know it is working or not.@Umair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check two things for this,

first check your **limage** is null or not, if it is null than hide your image view.

one another thing is check image is already exists on your server url. if not exists on server hide your image view.

you can try below code for that,

```
if(current.getLImage() == null || !imageExists(**yourImageUrl**)){
    Picasso.with(this.context).cancelRequest(holder.image);
    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


public static boolean imageExists(String URLName){
    HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpHead headMethod = new HttpHead(urlToImage);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(headMethod);
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode== HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is removing all the images even if they exist.

Comment: are you trying it in onBindViewHolder method or not ? and check your URL with comlpete image path not Uri.. @Umair

Comment: Can you please tell what would be way to use HttpURLConnection class with the imageExist() method you have provided.

Comment: try to check only one condition if(current.getLImage() == null || current.getLImage().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) and hide your image view.and let me know it works or not. @Umair

Comment: Well, I am stupid :P, I was checking if the whole url and not the value of limage ... when the check is applied on the limage , it works and hides the imageView.

Thanks by the way for your guidance.

Comment: yea.. ;) that's the problem.. no worry nice to help you. enjoy coding. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Try with this.**

If your Image URI is null.

```
if(uri == null){
    Picasso.with(this.context).cancelRequest(holder.image);
    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**Hope this helps you.**

Comment: I see what you did here but it didn't work. Still the imageView is shown as blank with the background I set for it.

Tried the View.Invisible as well but still getting the same result.

Comment: @Umair May be your blank image url have background part. show any of your blank image url.

Comment: @Umair Remove that part `android:background="@android:color/black"` from your XML `Image View`.

Comment: It is only removing the background color @jaydroider

Comment: @Umair I think now may be You have setup `android:layout_height="250dp"` this causing the problem. If it is blank then also it will show height to that image. So try to remove specific height change it to wrap content.Or may be change height of image view progrmatically if it is blank.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that cardview loses its height if the image is not null because of the wrap content. It should have a height of 250 or something like that if the image is available.

Comment: @Umair Try to change height progrmetically if image is null. Like `holder.image.getLayoutParams().height = 0;`. And for images which is not blank it will take `250dp` which you have given.

Comment: @Umair You should accept my answer if the things i suggested works for you. Thanks :).

Comment: Well, i would say that your answer was helpful, but while troubleshooting, i was thinking about this line written by @tejas
"""and check your URL with comlpete image path not Uri... """ and from this line i realize that i should use "limage" attribute to check whether it is null or not.... 

And as a beginner at stackoverflow, i dont know whether i should revert the accepted answers or not !

Comment: @Umair Brother I thought that you might have already  your URI contains data of limage so i have not suggested that part. You can still accept my answer if you want to revert Thanks :).